# All objects disappear in render mode blender 2.8 (eevee)

Tags: rendering, objects, object-mode

I start up a clean fresh project nothing is hidden and when I go to render mode everything is gone even when I try it on the default cube, eevee render mode and lookdev both. can only view it in object mode or cycles. please help the outlines are still there just not the objects[image]

Comment: @ben were you able to resolve this? I have the same thing happening

Comment: Try to pick focus object in camera settings or/and change lamp to sun and see if it helps.

Comment: @niraj no I haven't gotten it resolved im just gonna have to go back to 2.7 for now, almost a month with no resolve